# The spectrum of $S$ is a countable set?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Suppose $K:[0,1]\times[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function.
Let us define $S:L^2[0,1]\rightarrow L^2[0,1]$ by
$$(Sf)(x)=f(x)+ \int^1_0K(x,y)f(y)dy$$
Is the spectrum of $S$ a countable set? Why?

Comment: The $h$ was a typo for $f$, right???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Tf(x)=\int_0^{1} K(x,y) f(y)dy$. As is well-known this a compact operator. Non-zero points in its spectrum consists of at most countably many eigen values (converging to $0$ of there are in finitely many of them). These are standard facts about compact operators. Now just note that $S=T+I$ so $\sigma (S) =\{\lambda +1 : \lambda \in \sigma (T)\}$.

Comment: It works for any $K \in L^{2}([0,1]\times [0,1])$.